# How to configure node.js so it works properly on an actual web server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, web, socket.io

I have a simple node.js/socket.io chat program which is based almost entirely on [this tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/). It works flawlessly on my local machine, when I connect to it using `localhost:3000`. I then attempted to put it on my webserver so that anyone could go to `mydomain.com/experiments/thing.html` and access this same program. I could not for the life of me get this to work properly. The HTML loaded fine, but in the console I saw lots of 404 errors relating to socket.io. I tried for a very long time to search for solutions but I couldn't find any tutorials that mentioned how to set something like this up beyond `localhost`.

So, what I would like help with is setting up this code so that if a user goes to `mydomain.com/experiments/whatever.html`, this code will work just as if I had navigated to `localhost:3000` in its current state.

Here's my code:

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('other.html', { root : __dirname});
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("new connection, user " + socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("user " + socket.id + " disconnected.");
  });
});
```

Client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thing</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="commandLine" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('command', $('#commandLine').val());
        $('#commandLine').val('');
        return false;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Help is very much appreciated, I feel quite lost because I honestly don't know what I'm doing here. I'm very new to node.js in general.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I just want to make sure you know that you have to be able to run nodejs on your server. That is, you must have node installed on your server and run your chat server there.

Then, you can either have node serve on port 80, that is the HTTP port, directly, or have another web server in front, proxying to your node server. The second way is more common, and usually people opt to use nginx in front.

For nginx, you would have a configuration directive like this:

```
location /experiments {
  proxy_pass       http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_set_header Host      $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

This makes all requests to `/experiments` (or anything path starting with that) go to your node server.

With that in place, nginx and node running, you would then point your browser to `mydomain.com/experiments` and it should work.